# The element type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget' . (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, list, dart, widget

```
 postModel.loading
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
                :
            ...renderVideoCards()
```

This code is part of the column the part that was generating error is ( ...renderVideoCards() ). So let me know where i am going wrong and what should i do to reslove this error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign List type to Widget. You need to change it to a single widget to assign in Widget.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the spread operator `...` doesn't work well together with the ternary expression. I believe writing it like this would solve it for you:

```
if (postModel.loading) Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) 
else ...renderVideoCards(),
```

or alternatively write it like this:

```
...postModel.loading
  ? [Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())]
  : renderVideoCards()
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that your `renderVideoCards()` function returns a `List<Widget>`.
So you are trying to assign a List somewhere where you should assing a single Widget.

You can fix this problem by using a `Column` or a `Row`: that is a single Widget with multiple children.

```
postModel.loading
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
                :
            ...Column(children: renderVideoCards())
```